# HTML tables - How to use rowspan properly?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want to create a table like:

```
T1----T2----T3
--------------
      B1
A1    B2    C1
      B3
```

I'm using the following code:

```
   <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>T1</th>
                <th>T2</th>
                <th>T3</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="3">A1</td>
                <tr>
                    <td>B1</td>
                    <tr>
                        <td>B2</td>
                    </tr>
                    <td>C1</td>
                </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/90yegr6f/

I have problems with **C1**. How to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to focus on doing things one row at a time. Deal with everything in the first row. Then start a new row and deal with everything in that.

So the first row contains A1, B1 and C1.

```
<tr>
    <td>A1
    <td>B1
    <td>C1
```

The second row contains only B2

```
<tr>
    <td>B2
```

and so on.

Now, you want the first and last cells of the first row to span multiple rows:

```
<tr>
    <td rowspan=3>A1
    <td>B1
    <td rowspan=3>C1
```

Which gives you:

```html
<table class=table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>T1
      <th>T2
      <th>T3
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan=3>A1
      <td>B1
      <td rowspan=3>C1      
    <tr>
      <td>B2
    <tr>
      <td>B3
</table>
```